# Why does GCC not seem to have the filesystem standard library?

Tags: c++, gcc, raspberry-pi, c++17, gcc6

i'm facing a problem with filesystem library, it should be included in c++17 compiler, after 2 days i tried to install gcc-7.0.2 in raspberry pi but it didn't work, it couldn't recognize the command gcc-7 or g++-7 or even `-std=c++17` so i had to install g++-6 and gcc-6 using `apt-get install`
anyway, after installing the 6 version the compiler include c++17.
i'm using codeblocks as IDE, i had to add a new compiler and add the option -std=c++17 to enable it,but in the main code when i include the filesystem library it says no such file or directory.

my question is, how i can add the c++17 compiler and its library (like filesystem) correctly ??

Comment: Just because the switch says "C++17" doesn't mean that it implements *all* of C++17.

Comment: More specifically, it can only implement the *language* parts. The *library* parts are outside the compiler's purview.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Well, the compiler switches are also used to activate the library parts, since they're included with the compiler in the distro. But you're right that libstdc++ is updated separately from gcc.

Comment: @Nicol It's not updated seperately at all: specific GCC releases are quite tightly bound to specific libstdc++ snapshots. The version numbering works slightly different and both are developed semi-independently (as language feature implementation in the compiler permits).

Comment: @rubenvb If I install gcc 8 in Ubuntu, will I have 2 different libstdc++ library or merely the original one get updated?

Comment: @Rick you'll probably have two even though the newer one should work as a drop-in replacement for the old one.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

`GCC v7` still does not implement [<filesystem>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/filesystem) but it does have the *Filesystem Technical Specification* which is in [<experimental/filesystem>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/experimental/filesystem)

```
#include <experimental/filesystem>

// for brevity
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;

int main()
{
    fs::path p = "/path/to/my/file"; // etc...
}
```

This is also available in `GCC v6`.

To link with the library you need to add `-lstdc++fs` to the command line.

**Note:** There may be some minor differences between the current *Technical Specification* and the final draft of [<filesystem>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/filesystem) that is decided upon by the Standards Committee.

**Note 2:** `GCC v8` now implements [<filesystem>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/filesystem) with the `-std=c++17` flag.

Comment: so it was right that gcc v7 not completed yet, anyway, adding experimental/filesystem works fine, thank you for that.

Comment: @shadow Support for `C++17` is not complete, no. Mainly because `C++17` has not yet been finalized by the ISO Standards Committee. It will probably take a few months after that for `GCC` to become feature complete.

Comment: @Galik Why wouldn’t GCC be feature complete by the time C++17 is published? The C++17 draft has been feature-complte for months, and if I’m reading the [standardization process](https://www.iso.org/stage-codes.html#40.20) right, it won’t be published until [some time after October 30th](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2017-06-12+%2B+20+weeks). That should be plenty of time, since they’re [done with the core language](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx1z) and [mostly done with the library](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.201z).

Comment: @DanielH According to the records the `std::filesystem` did not arrive in `GCC` until `v8.1` which was published in `May 2018` which is *more than 6 months* after the `C++17 Standard` was published. Even then it was considered *"experimental"* until `GCC v9.1` which was published in `May 2019`.

Comment: I am using GCC 9.3 on Ubuntu 20.04 and `<filesystem>` did not work (even with `-std=c++17` flag). Using the experimental worked thanks to this answer.

Comment: @Sasan then you must be doing something wrong, because GCC 9.3 supports the C++17 `<filesystem>` features.

Answer (score 5):

First you should take at look at [C++17 Support in GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx17)

### GCC 8

> Runtime Library (libstdc++)
>
> - Improved experimental support for C++17, including the following features:
>
>   - Deduction guides to support class template argument deduction.
>   - `std::filesystem` implementation.
>   - `std::char_traits<char>` and `std::char_traits<wchar_t>` are usable in constant expressions.
>   - `std::to_chars` and `std::from_chars` (for integers only, not for floating point types).

src: https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-8/changes.html#libstdcxx

### GCC 9

> Runtime Library (libstdc++)
>
> - Improved support for C++17, including:
>
>   - The C++17 implementation is no longer experimental.
>   - Parallel algorithms and `<execution>` (requires Thread Building Blocks 2018 or newer).
>   - `<memory_resource>`.
>   - Using the types and functions in `<filesystem>` does not require linking with `-lstdc++fs` now.

src: https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-9/changes.html#libstdcxx