# how to use std::filesystem on gcc 8?

Tags: c++, gcc, namespaces

I have updated version of gcc, gcc --version produces the following output

```
    gcc (Ubuntu 8.1.0-5ubuntu1~16.04) 8.1.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

i can include filesystem in header file without any error

```
#include<filesystem>
```

But when i try to access the namespace filesystem like below then i get the error

```
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
```

**Error message**

```
error: ‘filesystem’ is not a namespace-name
 namespace fs = std::filesystem;
```

This seems to be weird since the gcc 8 has support for std::filesystem and it is not available in namespace, am i doing anything wrong in accessing std::filesystem?

and yes i built with -std=c++17

Comment: Do you build with `-std=c++17` (it is a C++17 feature after all)?

Comment: Are you compiling with `-std=c++17` or `-std=gnu++17`?

Comment: yes i built with -std=c++17

Comment: Perhaps relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45867379/why-does-gcc-not-seem-to-have-the-filesystem-standard-library

Comment: @Tas it was about gcc v7, gcc v8 already supports std::filesystem

Comment: Now is then the time to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us. And also show us how you build the source.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Add the filesystem library as an argument to your compiler that will be forwarded to the linker. Also make sure you are using C++17. Both g++ and clang++ accepts this particular format:

```
--std=c++17 -lstdc++fs
```

Comment: it didnt work, i have accidentally removed the namespace line when i made the  previous reply, still i get the same error.

Comment: Well, linking would probably work but you're blocked by problems that doesn't even get you that far. Try some filesystem examples on [std::filesystem @ cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=std%3A%3Afilesystem) and if that doesn't work, just edit the question.

Comment: @Naveen Did you ever figure out what was wrong? This old answer still gets upvotes so it seems it helps others :-)

Comment: Unfortunately no, none of the solutions worked, i stopped programming in c++ after that :-)

Comment: @Naveen :-D Oh no, that's unfortunate. You may be happy to know that the status of the compilers have improved greatly since then and I'm sure we could work it out if you gave C++ another chance :-)

Comment: If it doesn't work for you, make sure you're putting `-lstdc++fs` after the input file names, and make sure that your gcc is new enough (`gcc --version`).

Comment: `--std=c++17` is still necessary to use parts of `<filesystem>` in gcc 9.3.0 (this is the version that Ubuntu 20.04 supports) , and the implementation is still not complete. I was surprised that even even after 3 years the situation is still a bit rough. Since I only need a couple things out of `<filesystem>` I'm considering pursuing other options (even ones that are less portable and might require a different implementation for Windows).

Comment: @jrh `--std=c++17` or `--std=c++<any version after c++17>` will be needed for as long as C++17 or later is not the default version that the compiler uses so that's hardly surprising. What part of the `<filesystem>` implementation is not complete in [tag:g++]?

Comment: @TedLyngmo The post I read that mentioned that `<filesystem>` was incomplete was outdated I think. The [g++ standards support page](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html) seems to say that C++17 has "almost full support". Maybe it isn't that surprising that C++17 was still not complete in 2019, maybe gcc always needed [some time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44735016)  to implement the latest standard into the compiler. Still it caught me off guard.

Comment: As an aside VS2013 has limited C++11 support, but (rather confusingly), it appears to do the opposite strategy, and opts you into using their cherry picked C++11 features unless you explicitly say you want to use a certain C++ standard. FWIW the VS 2013 strategy is more annoying to deal with in 2020.

Comment: @jrh The C++17 language support may not be 100% but what's relevant is the state of the standard [library](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2017) implementation. It seems gcc 8 has [non-conforming `basic_fstream` path overloads](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support#C.2B.2B17_library_features) but I'm not sure if that's the case in gcc 9 or later.

Comment: despite not necessary anymore, seems backwards-compatible and also works with gcc9.

Comment: @CrocDialer People using LTS OS:es may still stumble upon this.

Answer (score 8):

> Because of the silly rep system, I can't make this a comment on slashmais's answer.

**When using an IDE, make sure that you also set the compiler to be used to GCC8 or above.**

In my case, despite being installed, CodeLite was using a lower version of GCC and causing headaches (re: not finding the header)!

Manually setting CodeLite to use `gcc-8` (instead of just `gcc` fixed this problem.

Comment: Up for shortening the miserable sub-100 transient period we've all hated. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an IDE, eg codeblocks, then make sure the default compiler flags for gcc: -std=c++17 is set, not just the current project's, but the global flags.

Had this issue with CB and setting this flag under [Settings/Compiler] fixed it (no need for adding the lib)