# std::filesystem linker errors with Qt creator

Tags: c++, qt, g++, linker-errors, std-filesystem

First, yes, I saw this topic:
[How to avoid std::filesystem linker errors with Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55318924/how-to-avoid-stdfilesystem-linker-errors-with-qt)

I have my c++ project and there I used a std::filesystem .I **can** compile it with cmd ( g++ (GCC) 9.2.0 )and for example:

```
g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Wconversion-null -c client.cpp -o c.o -lstdc++fs
```

but with this .pro file:

```
LIBS += -lws2_32
LIBS += -lstdc++fs

QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++17
CONFIG -= app_bundle

QMAKE_LFLAGS += -lstdc++fs

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

SOURCES += \
        client.cpp \
        logmsg.cpp \
        main.cpp

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

HEADERS += \
    client.h \
    includes.h
```

I **cannot** do it and I cannot understand why.

Error:

```
   filesystem: No such file or directory
    #include <filesystem>

          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: The mentioned error is not a linkage error. Compiler fails to find the include file. Might be a wrong compiler version. Can you show the code where the filesystem header included?

Comment: Which QMake/Qt version is this? The full argument list of the failing g++ call might also be interesting (to see where it differs from your manual call).

Comment: @vahancho totally right ,choosed wrong compiler version in kits' settings. Thanks for help.