# undefined reference to 'std::filesystem' using Bazel build

Tags: c++, filesystems, bazel

trying to pull and build [Visqol](https://github.com/google/visqol) following the instructions provided for Linux. I downloaded Bazel, everything seems fine. But when I try to execute with `bazel build :visqol -c opt` i get the following errors

```
bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/_objs/visqol/main.o:main.cc:function main: error: undefined reference to 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::_M_split_cmpts()'
bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/_objs/visqol/main.o:main.cc:function main: error: undefined reference to 'std::filesystem::status(std::filesystem::__cxx11::path const&)'
bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/_objs/visqol_lib/commandline_parser.o:commandline_parser.cc:function Visqol::VisqolCommandLineParser::FileExists(Visqol::FilePath const&): error: undefined reference to 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::_M_split_cmpts()'
bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/_objs/visqol_lib/commandline_parser.o:commandline_parser.cc:function Visqol::VisqolCommandLineParser::FileExists(Visqol::FilePath const&): error: undefined reference to 'std::filesystem::status(std::filesystem::__cxx11::path const&)'
bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/_objs/visqol_lib/commandline_parser.o:commandline_parser.cc:function Visqol::VisqolCommandLineParser::ReadFilesToCompare(Visqol::FilePath const&): error: undefined reference to 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::_M_split_cmpts()'
bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/_objs/visqol_lib/commandline_parser.o:commandline_parser.cc:function Visqol::VisqolCommandLineParser::BuildFilePairPaths(Visqol::CommandLineArgs const&): error: undefined reference to 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::_M_split_cmpts()'
bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/_objs/visqol_lib/commandline_parser.o:commandline_parser.cc:function Visqol::VisqolCommandLineParser::BuildFilePairPaths(Visqol::CommandLineArgs const&): error: undefined reference to 'std::filesystem::status(std::filesystem::__cxx11::path const&)'
bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/_objs/visqol_lib/commandline_parser.o:commandline_parser.cc:function Visqol::VisqolCommandLineParser::BuildFilePairPaths(Visqol::CommandLineArgs const&): error: undefined reference to 'std::filesystem::status(std::filesystem::__cxx11::path const&)'
bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/_objs/visqol_lib/commandline_parser.o:commandline_parser.cc:function Visqol::VisqolCommandLineParser::Parse(int, char**): error: undefined reference to 'std::filesystem::current_path[abi:cxx11]()'
bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/_objs/visqol_lib/commandline_parser.o:commandline_parser.cc:function Visqol::VisqolCommandLineParser::Parse(int, char**): error: undefined reference to 'std::filesystem::current_path[abi:cxx11]()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've seen similar issues in c++ on the web but most of these are building with make commands and solve this by adding the `-lstdc++fs` or `LDLIBS=-lstdc++fs` options. However, those are unrecognized for Bazel

I'm on Debian 10.13 and my Bazel version is 5.3.1, my c++ version seems to be 8.3.0

Comment: Does [how to use std::filesystem on gcc 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53202056/7582247) answer your question?

Comment: [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: In `.bazelrc`, change the line `build --linkopt=-ldl` into `build --linkopt=-lstdc++fs -ldl`

Comment: @TedLyngmo As said, the -lstdc++fs is not recognized with Bazel

Comment: Did you add `-lstdc++fs`  like I proposed? What does bazel have to say about it? I would have guessed that bazel would only forward the option to the compiler/linker.

Comment: My bad,your solution was correct i just had a typo error. Thank you so much, you can post it as an answer, I'll accept it
The correct line is: "build --linkopt=-lstdc++fs"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In accordance with [how to use std::filesystem on gcc 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53202056/7582247), change the line `build --linkopt=-ldl` in `.bazelrc` into:

```
build --linkopt=-lstdc++fs -ldl
```

You could also open a ticket in the [Visgol repo](https://github.com/google/visqol) and tell them about this problem and get a proper solution in the future releases of Visgol.