# Finding path of execution of C++ program

Tags: c++, path

In C++ command-line program I am working, I require to find path of execution i.e. path from where .exe file is called. For example, if file is stored if `D:\stored\location\` but it is called from some other directory , like `D:\executed\here\`, I should get `D:\executed\here\` as path.
Command prompt should look somewhat like this:-

```
D:\executed\here> D:\stored\location\program_name.exe getpath
Path of execution is : D:\executed\here
```

I tried to use GetModuleFileName as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528298/get-path-of-executable) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875249/how-to-get-current-directory), but I got `\stored\here`.

Is there a  cross-platform way to find "execution path"?

Note:- I am using VSCode.

Edit: version of compiler is: g++ (i686-posix-dwarf-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0
Side note:- for some reason after including `#include<filesystem>` , `std::filesystem` is showing error : 'std::filesystem' has not been declared", so i am not able to use filesystem.h

Comment: What you seem to want is the current [*working directory*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory). A quick search should tell you the Windows-specific function needed to get it.

Comment: As for the `std::filesystem` error, please post that as a different question. Remember to include a [mcve].

Comment: Concerning `std::filesystem`: It was introduced with C++17. So, you may have to force this in your compiler with `-std=c++17`. As I incidentally solved exactly your problem a few days ago (using the same Q/As like you), I noticed also that I had to link with `-lstdc++fs` on Linux (g++ 8.2). On VS2019, it worked out of the box (with `/std:c++17` of course).

Comment: What I wonder: If `std::filesystem` wouldn't be available at all, `#include<filesystem>` should have been failed beforehand...

Comment: If your g++ compiler is g++ 8.1, chances are good that you already have C++17 support. ([SO: Why does GCC not seem to have the filesystem standard library?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45867491/7478597)). Maybe, you have similar issues like the one I mentioned for `g++ 8.2` on my Debian inst.

Answer (score 1):

### Answer for C++17

The MinGW seems to be shipped currently with g++ 6.3 which I consider as quite old. So, I wrote another [Answer for C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65550003/7478597).

---

Incidentally, I solved the same problem with the help of
[**SO: Get path of executable**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1528493/7478597)
a few days ago.

I've put the relevant part into an MCVE:

```
// Declaration (Header):

// standard C++ header:
#include <filesystem>

// returns file path of this executable
std::filesystem::path getExecPath();

/**************************************************************************/

// Definition (C++ Source):

// standard C++ header:
#include <string>

// OS header:
#ifdef _MSC_VER // Is this MSVC?
#include <windows.h>
#else // (not) _MSC_VER // Then it's hopefully Linux/g++.
#include <unistd.h>
#endif // _MSC_VER

std::filesystem::path getExecPath()
{
#ifdef _MSC_VER // Is this MSVC?
  std::wstring path(1024, L'\0');
  const DWORD len
    = GetModuleFileNameW(NULL, &path[0], (DWORD)path.size());
  if (!len) return std::filesystem::path(); // ERROR!
  path.resize(len);
  return std::filesystem::path(path);
#else // (not) _MSC_VER // Then it's hopefully Linux/g++.
  std::string path(1024, '\0');
  ssize_t len
    = readlink("/proc/self/exe", &path[0], path.size());
  if (len < 0) return std::filesystem::path(); // ERROR!
  path.resize(len);
  return path;
#endif // _MSC_VER
}

/**************************************************************************/

// Test:

// standard C++ header:
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout
    << "Exec. Path:   " << getExecPath() << '\n'
    << "Current Dir.: " << std::filesystem::current_path() << '\n';
}
```

First, I tried on [**coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fcc8ad528760b657):

```
g++ -std=c++17 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && mkdir test ; cd test ; ../a.out
Exec. Path:   "/tmp/1609670485.1182494/a.out"
Current Dir.: "/tmp/1609670485.1182494/test"
```

Note: The version of `g++` on coliru is [**g++ 10.2.0**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b0e8c58aca919661) (at the time of writing).

---

I added a `CMakeLists.txt` to test this on my local box:

```
project(ExecPath)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.0)

set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
if (UNIX)
  # std::filesystem which was added in C++17
  # seems to need an extra lib. in g++.
  # This might be version dependent...
  link_libraries(-lstdc++fs)
endif()

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin")

add_executable(testExecPath testExecPath.cc)
```

---

The MCVE built and run in **Visual Studion 2019**.

Output:

```
Exec. Path:   "D:\\ds32737\\Entwicklung\\tests\\C++\\execPath\\build-VS2019\\bin\\Debug\\testExecPath.exe"
Current Dir.: "D:\\ds32737\\Entwicklung\\tests\\C++\\execPath\\build-VS2019"
```

---

Finally, I tested this on Debian-Linux (in a VM with **g++ 8.3.0**).

Test Session:

```
ds32737@debian:/mnt/hostd/Entwicklung/tests/C++/execPath$ mkdir build-debian
ds32737@debian:/mnt/hostd/Entwicklung/tests/C++/execPath$ cd build-debian/
ds32737@debian:/mnt/hostd/Entwicklung/tests/C++/execPath/build-debian$ cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 8.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 8.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /mnt/hostd/Entwicklung/tests/C++/execPath/build-debian
ds32737@debian:/mnt/hostd/Entwicklung/tests/C++/execPath/build-debian$ cmake --build .
Scanning dependencies of target testExecPath
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/testExecPath.dir/testExecPath.cc.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable bin/testExecPath
[100%] Built target testExecPath
ds32737@debian:/mnt/hostd/Entwicklung/tests/C++/execPath/build-debian$ bin/testExecPath 
Exec. Path:   "/mnt/hostd/Entwicklung/tests/C++/execPath/build-debian/bin/testExecPath"
Current Dir.: "/mnt/hostd/Entwicklung/tests/C++/execPath/build-debian"
ds32737@debian:/mnt/hostd/Entwicklung/tests/C++/execPath/build-debian$
```

The `g++ 8.3` is the default on my Debian installation which I did quite recently. It's a bit aged.

So, I had to add `-lstdc++fs` to come around link issues with `std::filesystem`.
Please, note, that this was not necessary with `g++ 10.2` I used in coliru.

---

Please, note that I took care that the current working directory was not the directory where the executable is located in, in every case.

For the solution of this task, I took care about encoding issues.
(In the past, I've often struggled with file systems and encoding issues as soon as everything else than ASCII characters appear in file paths.)

Thus, I used `GetModuleHandleW()` for the Windows implementation which returns the file path in UTF-16.

On Linux, I assume that UTF-8 is used always.

Strictly speaking, `std::filesystem::path` is even not really necessary.
Instead, the path could be returned e.g. as `std::string`.
For this, the Windows impl. could convert UTF-16 to UTF-8 to provide a granted encoding on any platform.

Answer (score 1):

### Answer for C++11

Out of curiosity, I installed the MinGW g++ into my git-bash (following [How to install gcc in Git Bash (Windows)](https://yichaoou.github.io/tutorials/software/2016/06/28/git-bash-install-gcc).
That worked immediately but the first bad surprise came soon:

```
ds32737@lapeks415-017 MINGW64 /d/ds32737/Entwicklung/tests/C++/execPath
$ which g++
/d/MinGW/bin/g++

ds32737@lapeks415-017 MINGW64 /d/ds32737/Entwicklung/tests/C++/execPath
$ g++ --version
g++.exe (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Oh, oops! **g++ 6.3**. That explains OPs problems with `std::filesystem` (and I got them on my side too).

So, I modified the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65549206/7478597) to back-port this to C++11.

My C++11 conform MCVE:

```
// Declaration (Header):

// standard C++ header:
#include <string>

// returns file path of this executable
std::string getExecPath();

/**************************************************************************/

// Definition (C++ Source):

// standard C++ header:
#include <cstring>
#include <codecvt>
#include <locale>

// OS header:
#ifdef _WIN32 // Is this Windows?
#include <windows.h>
#else // (not) _WIN32 // Then it's hopefully Linux.
#include <unistd.h>
#endif // _WIN32

std::string getExecPath()
{
#ifdef _WIN32 // Is this Windows?
  std::wstring path(1024, L'\0');
  const DWORD len
    = GetModuleFileNameW(NULL, &path[0], (DWORD)path.size());
  if (!len) return std::string(); // ERROR!
  path.resize(len);
  std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> convU16ToU8;
  return convU16ToU8.to_bytes(path);
#else // (not) _WIN32 // Then it's hopefully Linux.
  std::string path(1024, '\0');
  ssize_t len
    = readlink("/proc/self/exe", &path[0], path.size());
  if (len < 0) return std::string(); // ERROR!
  path.resize(len);
  return path;
#endif // _WIN32
}

std::string getCWD()
{
#ifdef _WIN32 // Is this Windows?
  std::wstring path(1024, L'\0');
  const DWORD len
    = GetCurrentDirectoryW(path.size(), &path[0]);
  if (!len) return std::string(); // ERROR!
  path.resize(len);
  std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> convU16ToU8;
  return convU16ToU8.to_bytes(path);
#else // (not) _WIN32 // Then it's hopefully Linux.
  std::string path(1024, '\0');
  if (!getcwd(&path[0], path.size())) return std::string(); // ERROR!
  size_t len = std::strlen(path.c_str());
  path.resize(len);
  return path;
#endif // _WIN32
}

/**************************************************************************/

// Test:

// standard C++ header:
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout
    << "Exec. Path:   " << getExecPath() << '\n'
    << "Current Dir.: " << getCWD() << '\n';
}
```

---

Test Session in MinGW (**g++ 6.3**):

```
ds32737@lapeks415-017 MINGW64 /d/ds32737/Entwicklung/tests/C++/execPath/C++11
$ g++ -std=c++11 -O2 testExecPath.cc && mkdir test ; cd test ; ../a.exe
Exec. Path:   D:\ds32737\Entwicklung\tests\C++\execPath\C++11\a.exe
Current Dir.: D:\ds32737\Entwicklung\tests\C++\execPath\C++11\test

ds32737@lapeks415-017 MINGW64 /d/ds32737/Entwicklung/tests/C++/execPath/C++11/test
$
```

---

Test on [**coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7ab6567f07921332):

```
g++ -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && mkdir test ; cd test ; ../a.out
Exec. Path:   /tmp/1609678428-623235554/a.out
Current Dir.: /tmp/1609678428-623235554/test
```

---

**Note:**

I was not aware of this as I've never used g++ in MinGW before:
`_WIN32` is defined in MinGW as well, and the respective code is used (and has to be used).
(Before, I used `_MSC_VER` which activates the Windows code for MSVC only.
In this case, I got a compiler error as `readlink()` was not available.
Even if it would've been it probably hadn't done what it's supposed to on Linux.)