# Is filesystem failing just becasue of g++ versions?

Tags: c++, g++

I am having a problem building a program that uses

```
#include <filesystem>
```

My situation is the following:

- I have Ubuntu 20.04
- In my system:

  g++ --version
  g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0

With this I can build a simple program with filesystem with

```
gcc -o test test.cpp -std=c++1z -lstdc++ -lstdc++fs
```

However, I have also a docker container.

Inside this docker container I have

```
 g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
```

When I try to build here the program I got

```
fatal error: filesystem: No such file or directory
 #include <filesystem>
```

Does g++ 7.5.0 support filesystem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does GCC not seem to have the filesystem standard library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45867379/why-does-gcc-not-seem-to-have-the-filesystem-standard-library)

Comment: Seems like you answered your own question

Comment: I feel like gcc (and every major compiler) has a status page where you can easily see where support lies for versions of C++. cppreference has one that includes all major compilers as well. I feel like a few minutes googling would have been far more enlightening and fulfilling than waiting to be drip-fed. For your newer gcc, it'd also be `-std=c++17`. `1z` might not translate literally to `17` and might be missing even more features. At least that's how it is when clang transitions.

Comment: so... g++ 7.5.0 does not support filesystem, does it?

Comment: g++ 7 is fairly old. The current version of g++ is 11, with 12 on the horizon.